# Scope of dynamically allocated memory in function

Tags: c, function, scope, malloc

I have a function

```
int*AllocatedMemory(int n){
    int*p=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    return p;
}
```

will the allocated memory lose scope after leaving function and hence get freed?

Comment: Isn't this something you can easily check for yourself in a small console application?

Comment: @Kippie Things that fall under undefined behaviour (though this doesn't) can work on one compiler but not another. One simple test doesn't say enough. One needs to know the theory.

Answer (score 7):

No. Memory allocated with `malloc` have nothing to do with scope and needs to be freed with `free` (or will be freed when the program terminates).

Comment: does that mean the memory allocated with `malloc` never lose scope until it is forced `free` or the program terminates?

Comment: @PrakashGautam It means exactly that.